# Add markers NAME on the map using Plotly Scattermapbox traces

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I need support to add markers NAME on the map using Plotly Scattermapbox traces.

The below code shows markers and lines, I want to show markers name on the map:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
    mode = "markers+lines",
    lon = [10, 20, 30],
    lat = [10, 20,30],
    marker = {'size': 10}))

fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
    mode = "markers+lines",
    lon = [-50, -60,40],
    lat = [30, 10, -20],
    marker = {'size': 10}))

fig.update_layout(
    margin ={'l':0,'t':0,'b':0,'r':0},
    mapbox = {
        'center': {'lon': 10, 'lat': 10},
        'style': "stamen-terrain",
        'center': {'lon': -20, 'lat': -20},
        'zoom': 1})

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mode = "markers+text+lines"` and also provide a text field

> mode – Determines the drawing mode for this scatter trace. If the
> provided mode includes “text” then the text elements appear at the
> coordinates. Otherwise, the text elements appear on hover.

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
    mode = "markers+text+lines",
    lon = [10, 20, 30],
    lat = [10, 20,30],
    marker = {'size': 10},
    text = ["name1", "name2", "name3"], 
    textposition = "bottom right")
)
```

There is a known bug that prevents non mapbox styles from showing the text

https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4110

Logging in to mapbox and creating a new custom, solved this issue for some people:

https://community.plotly.com/t/scattermapbox-doesnt-work-with-marker-mode-as-text/35065/4

Comment: The text is showing over the mouse. Is it possible to get it in the Map?

Comment: some maps prevent rendering of text on top of them, you might need a custom official mapbox.  If you can use a mapbox style (with a free token) the problem disappears